# How to remove/delete particular member or element from static "Array of TPoint"?

Tags: arrays, delphi, element, point

I want to remove/delete particular member or element from static "Array of TPoint". How to do this?

Comment: `array of TPoint` is a dynamic array in Delphi language; a static array is for example `array[0..10] of TPoint`.

Comment: Sounds like you'd be better off with TList<TPoint>

Comment: @David hoiw is it better ? TList<T> uses TArray<T> under the hood. You can offer him some linked list - that would really be better.

Comment: @Arioch'The The exact same reasoning leads to this. The Delphi compiler produces machine code. So why bother with the compiler at all? Just write machine code by hand.

Comment: @David that would be close if `array of TPoint` and `TList<TPoint>` were assignment-compatible. They are not, you know. If TS needs `array of TPoint` then suggesting him incompatible type should have some merits other than sacing few lines just to waste them later on typecasting adapters

Comment: @Arioch Well, obviously you'd change entirely to TList<TPoint>. It would be silly to try to mix and match.

Answer (score 5):

If by "static" you mean "non-dynamic" (ie. fixed-size array), then you can't. The best thing you can do is to move it to the end of the array and then mark the last TPoint in some way that will allow you to ignore it on subsequent passes.

If you are talking about a dynamic (ie. variable-sized array, ie. `VAR A : ARRAY OF TPoint;`) then you can use the following routine:

```
TYPE
  TPointArray = ARRAY OF TPoint;

PROCEDURE RemoveIndex(VAR ARR : TPointArray ; Index: INTEGER);
  VAR
    I : INTEGER;

  BEGIN
    IF (Index<LOW(Arr)) OR (Index>HIGH(Arr)) THEN EXIT;
    FOR I:=Index TO PRED(HIGH(ARR)) DO ARR[I]:=ARR[SUCC(I)];
    SetLength(ARR,PRED(LENGTH(ARR)))
  END;
```

Comment: The edit wasn't me disapproving your personal style, but trying to improve readability for the majority of readers.

Comment: @NGLN: No offense and not to start a long discussion (I have had them before), but how do you know what "the majority of readers" need to "improve readability"? Have you conducted a survey? I have my style, and you have yours. I don't correct your postings, so please don't correct mine - they will only be corrected back.

Comment: Out of wonder, how do you know what is upper case and what is lower? I mean I can see keywords are upper and most of the rest is also upper, but I can't reason why SetLength would be lower while Length is upper. (By "lower" I mean Pascal case...)

Comment: If an identifier is made up of multiple words, I use CamelCase. If it is a PASCAL/Delphi Language keyword or standard identifier of only one word, I usually use UPPERCASE. I never use purely lowercase.